# Can a column range be used with SUBSTITUTE

Tags: excel, substitution

I'm trying to use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(L11:L50),"Designer's Circle","Full-Page")
```

to return specific answers to specific input. But having trouble using a range of cells. I can get the formula to work with a **specific** cell. For example:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(L11,"Designer's Circle","Full-Page")
```

But not with a range

I have six different input possibilities in Column L and want to be able to substitute each of them with a different result in another part of the sheet.

What an I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you copy your row 11 formula down to row 50?

Comment: Hi Jos, I would except that I'm looking for different things in each row to populate another table off to the side. Each item would deliver a different result. For example: Members = Business Card; Actor's = Half-page; Designer's = Full page; ...and so on.

Comment: What kind of problem are you having?  As you've written it, seems to work OK here with a SPILL'd result showing the relevant substitutions.  Do you have an error message?  Or do you mean something else by "problem")?

Comment: ...and the column info is being generated by another form.

Comment: Hi Ron...I am. I get this error message when I try to place a range: "*There was a problem*
It looks like your formula is missing one or more open parentheses. If you don't want to enter a formula, begin your text with an apostrophe (')."

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE (L11:L50),"Designer’s Circle","Full Page")

Comment: I'm getting in over my head here...but maybe a nested formula? COUNTIF with SUBSTITUTE?  I have **no** idea if that's possible...just wondering...

Comment: I think you need to give a clearer example with expected results.

Comment: You have too many ) in your formula.

Comment: Scott: which parentheses?